# WhatsApp messages not being delivered in sequence

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to send multiple messages to a recipient in WhatsApp using Twilio's API. The messages needs to appear in sequence (e.g. A->B-C) but appears in random sequence (e.g C->B->A) when delivered. I have tried adding setTimeout() and other ways to slow down the execution, but it doesn't help

```
for (let i = 0; i <= listItems.length - 1; i++) {
    const item= $(listItems[i]).text();
    client.messages
        .create({
            body: item,
            to: 'whatsapp:', 
            from: 'whatsapp:', 
            })
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

To send a media message with WhatsApp, include the MediaUrl parameter with your HTTP POST request. This is exactly like sending an MMS message with Twilio Programmable SMS.

Here’s an example cURL script:

curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json 
--data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+13105555555" 
--data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+12125551234" 
--data-urlencode "Body=Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl." 
--data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png" 
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
This example will contact the WhatsApp destination (310) 555-5555 from the sender (212) 555-1234 via the WhatsApp app, and includes the image owl.png, and the following message:

Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl.
To make this script work for you, make the following updates, and then paste it into a terminal window:

Line 1 update with your Account SID.
Line 2 update with a valid destination.
Line 3 update with a valid WhatsApp sender number.
Unless your Twilio number has been enabled for WhatsApp in production, use your WhatsApp Sandbox number for sending messages.
Line 4 update with your desired message.
Note: A free-form message like this is only possible during a 24 hour user-initiated session. Unprompted messages have template requirements. For more information, see the Rules and Limitations section below.
Line 5 update with a valid media file url.
Line 6 update with your Account SID and Auth Token.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to send a media message, rather looking to send multiple text messages in a sequence to the same user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).